# How to send data range using ajax in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code where I am trying to get some data within a date range

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Start Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="datepickerF"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>End Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="datepickerT"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="pull" value="Pull Data" />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepickerF").datepicker();
                $("#datepickerT").datepicker();
            });

            $("#pull").on("click",function(){
                var url="something";
                var data=

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ,
                        success: function (data){}
                    });
            });

        </script>
```

But I am confused how can I send the date range in the data: . Is there any good solution to send the date range and get the data within that range here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the dates using `$("#datepickerF").datepicker('getDate');` however this returns a `Date` js object, surely you want to send the date to the server and you need a date in string format, so try with `$("#datepickerF").val()` since datepicker sets the value for the input in string format you can get it using `val()`.

Then depend on your controller requirements you can send the dates to the server as string in multiple formats, as this is not specified in your question you can for example send it as `JSON` object as:

```
$("#pull").on("click",function(){
    var url="something";
    var data= {"start" : $("#datepickerF").val(), "end" : $("#datepickerF").val()};

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data){}
    });
});
```

See this working <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ner53k8k/)</kbd>

Additionally if you need a specific date format, you can use `datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })` when you initialize your object, for example:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepickerF").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
    $("#datepickerT").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
});
```

see [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Hope this helps,